# What's going wrong with my java equals line?

Tags: java

The code below outputs `No succes: 01` and I don't know why. I've been busting my head for hours on this now...

```
//responseStr is {"theme":"01"}
String[] parts = responseStr.split(":");
parts[1] = parts[1].replace("\"", "");

if (parts[1].equals(01)){
    Log.v(TAG, "Success");
} else {
    Log.v(TAG, "No success: " + parts[1]);
}
```

Apparently, I'm really dumb. Should've added this as well `parts[1] = parts[1].replace("}", "");`

Comment: Double-quotes around `01`?

Comment: Either change the parts[1] to integer or 01 to string.

Comment: I edited the question with the solution. I feel so dumb now.

Comment: IMHO removing the question altogether is a better idea. I don't think anyone else will have any benefit from this one.

Comment: I can't since it's already been answered.

Answer (score 2):

`parts[i]` is an instance of `String`, `01` is Object of `Integer`, so they are **not** `equal`

Comment: additionally parts[1] will be 1, where at 01 = 1. Integers do not carry a forwards 0.

Comment: You can inspect the value of parts and then based on that you can decide what to compare against once

Answer (score 1):

```
//responseStr is {"theme":"01"}
String[] parts = responseStr.split(":");

if (parts[1].equals("01")){
    Log.v(TAG, "Success");
} else {
    Log.v(TAG, "No success: " + parts[1]);
}
```